# Amend 10 bits of 2 bytes

Tags: c#

In C#, how would I go about setting 2 bytes where the first 10 bits represent one decimal value and the next 6 represent a different decimal value?

So if the first value was '8' (first 10 bits) and the second '2' (remaining 6 bits), I need to end up with '0000001000 000010' inside a byte array.

Thanks!
Ad

Comment: Is that 10 bits or 10 bits? ;)

Comment: @demoncodemonkey : you mean `bytes or bits`? :)

Comment: Could be a requirement for interoperability with a legacy system. Some old systems had ridiculous ways of expecting data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UInt16 val1 = 8;
UInt16 val2 = 2;
UInt16 combined = (UInt16)((val1 << 6) | val2);
```

If you need it in a byte array, you can pass the result to the [`BitConverter.GetBytes` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes.aspx).

```
byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(combined);
```

Comment: `UInt16 combined = (val1 << 6) | val2;` does not compile, `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ushort'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @sll Just add a cast and it will.

Comment: Edited to add the cast from Int32 to UInt16.

Answer (score 1):

```
int val1 = 8;
int val2 = 2;

// First byte contains all but the 2 least significant bits from the first value.
byte byte1 = (byte)(val1 >> 2);

// Second byte contains the 2 least significant bits from the first value,
// shifted 6 bits left to become the 2 most significant bits of the byte,
// followed by the (at most 6) bits of the second value.
byte byte2 = (byte)((val1 & 4) << 6 | val2);

byte[] bytes = new byte[] { byte1, byte2 };

// Just for verification.
string s =
    Convert.ToString(byte1, 2).PadLeft(8, '0') + " " +
    Convert.ToString(byte2, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not accounting for any kind of overflow:

```
private static byte[] amend(int a, int b)
{
    // Combine the datum into a 16 bits integer
    var c = (ushort) ((a << 6) | (b));
    // Fragment the Int to bytes
    var ret = new byte[2];
    ret[0] = (byte) (c >> 8);
    ret[1] = (byte) (c);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ushort value = (8 << 6) | 2;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
```